# Is it possible to include an animated barplot in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, gganimate

Is it possible to include an animated barplot in my Shiny Dashboard. I have created animated barplots which are working in RStudio, however when I try and include them within my Shiny Dashboard they don't show.

Does anyone know if `gganimate` plots can be included in the dashboard.

I have included a shortened version of my code below.

```
library(gganimate)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

ui = dashboardPage(
  #Header
  dashboardHeader(title = "Irish Crime Analysis"),

  #Sidebar
  dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
    menuItem("Search", tabName = "search"),
    menuItem("Break Down", tabName = "breakDown")
  )
),

#Body
dashboardBody(tabItems(
# First tab content
tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
        fluidRow(
          valueBoxOutput("value1")
          ,valueBoxOutput("value2")
          ,valueBoxOutput("value3"),

          fluidRow(
            box(
              title= "Crime Grouped by Year"
              ,status = "primary"
              ,solidheader = TRUE
              ,collapsible = TRUE
              ,plotOutput("CrimeGroupbyYear", height = "300px")
            )
            ,box(
              title= "Count of Crime Categories over the Years"
              ,status = "primary"
              ,solidheader = TRUE
              ,collapsible = TRUE
              ,plotOutput("CrimeCatanimate", height = "300px"))))
))

),
# Second tab content #
tabItem(tabName = "search",
        fluidRow(
          h2("Search Set ups"),
          DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
        )))

server = function(input, output) {

output$CrimeCatanimate <- renderPlotly({
 ggplot(DF_YearsCombined, aes(CrimeCount, CrimeScore, color = CrimeCat)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  # gganimate specific bits:
  labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'Number of Crimes', y = 'Crime 
  Score') +
  transition_time(yearOnly) 
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: animated plots are actually files like gifs and mp4s which you can't render with `renderPlotly()`. I'm assuming you could render them somehow in a Shiny app, since Shiny supports native HTML and there is a [`<video>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: Can you provide your data `DF_YearsCombined` or a subset of the data using `dput`? It is not possible to execute your code because data is missing. Thanks.